# SwiftUI TabView not starting at leftmost view not animating

Tags: swiftui

I have a very minimal SwiftUI `TabView`.

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    
    @State private var currentTabSelection = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(currentTabSelection)")
            TabView(selection: $currentTabSelection) {
                Text("0").tag(0)
                Text("1").tag(1)
            }.tabViewStyle(.page)
        }
    }
}
```

I want to "start" at index 1, instead of 0. When I do, the view does not transition to the index 0 when changing the `selection` binding value **for the first time only**. Changing by swiping works, but either clicking on the build in buttons, as well as any other programmatic change (e.g. setting `currentTabSelection` to 0) does not work. See screen recording:

[image: screen recording of issue]

After switching back and force once, all works as expected. It also works as expected when initialising the `selection` at 0.

What am I doing wrong? Or is this a bug?

Edit: This also occurs when using strings as tags, whenever the initial value / tag is not the leftmost view.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine even when I add a button. Please provide the addtional code that shows the problem. Perhaps I'm not clear on what problem you see.

Answer (score 0):

It probably depends, exactly how you are implementing the programmatic change. This bit was missing from your example code.

In any case, you could try adding an `.animation` modifier to the `TabView`.

Also, be sure to test on a simulator or on a real device, don't rely on a preview.

In the updated example below, the text label that you had at the top of your `VStack` now has an `onTapGesture` that toggles the selection. It works first time without issues:

```swift
VStack {
    Text("\(currentTabSelection)")
        .onTapGesture {
            currentTabSelection = (currentTabSelection == 0 ? 1 : 0)
        }

    TabView(selection: $currentTabSelection) {
        Color.blue
            .overlay { Text("0").font(.largeTitle) }
            .tag(0)
        Color.orange
            .overlay { Text("1").font(.largeTitle) }
            .tag(1)
    }
    .foregroundStyle(.white)
    .tabViewStyle(.page)
    .animation(.easeInOut, value: currentTabSelection) //  ADDED
}
```

[image: Animation]